# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am developing a Web Application using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I create a couple of custom MembershipProvider and RoleProvider like bellow:

```
# Custom MembershipProviders
<membership defaultProvider="myMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="myMembershipProvider" type="WebApp1.Business.Auth.MyMembershipProvider" />
    <add name="adminMembershipProvider" type="WebApp1.Business.Auth.AdminMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>


# Custom RoleProviders
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="WebApp1.Business.Auth.MyRoleProvider" />
    <add name="AdminRoleProvider" type="WebApp1.Business.Auth.AdminRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

My intention is to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute called Logon that will use the "myMembershipProvider" and "MyRoleProvider"; and create another one called AdminLogon that will use "adminMembershipProvider" and "AdminRoleProvider".

The reason I am creating two custom AuthorizeAttributes is because I want to separate some methods that get the permissons of each role.

The question is, how can I set dynamically the default MembershipProvider and RoleProviders
inside both custom AuthorizeAttribute.

For example:

```
// Set the default MembershipProvider as adminMembershipProvider
// Set the default RoleProvidersas as AdminRoleProvider
[AdminLogon(Roles = "Administrador")]
public ActionResult Funcionarios()
{
    return View();
}


// Set the default MembershipProvider as myMembershipProvider
// Set the default RoleProvidersas as MyRoleProvider
[Logon(Roles = "Administrador")]
public ActionResult Funcionarios()
{
    return View();
}
```